# How to give style to a button of a popup

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this link: ./images/img1.jpg

What I am curious about is how can I use this to make this: ./css/plus.css

I want to include a css file into a popup I will make with JS. So I have to make ./css/plus.css path with ./images/img1.jpg path and put this into the popup by document.write

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/plus.css">
```

because that is the only path I get in the imgopen() function.

```
/* JavaScript */
function imgopen(image) {
    var newWindow=window.open("", "_blank", "width=450, height=400");
    newWindow.document.write("<img src=\""+image+"\" style=\"width: 100%\">");
    newWindow.document.write("<button id=\"close\" onclick=\"close_w()\">close</button>");
```

}

Or I can give the style options in the css directly to the button I will make in the popup, but I am not sure about whether it is possible or not to do like this:

```
var x=document.getElementById("close");
x.style.color="red";
```

Please help!

Comment: you can do it only after the element been added to the DOM (otherwise your selector can't find the element)

Comment: Instead of using `document.write()`, you can use `newWindow.document.createElement()` and `newWindow.document.body.appendChild()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for giving me new function :D I did not know createElement()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
newWindow.document.write("<img src='" + image +"' style='width: 100%;height:500px;'>");
```

Comment: What I want is to give style to the button but thanks for the replying

Comment: you can use it similarly for button as well.
newWindow.document.write("<button style='width: 100%;height:500px;'>close</button>");